# Schedule future UNUserNotificationCenter with condition and limits (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I know this has been asked several times but there is no concrete solution I have found over the SO.I am working on iOS app and I am using userNotification and all things are working fine but then I have to use the recurring/repeat notifications so here are the conditions that I have to fulfill and wondering how

> **Case: Show notification to user to check for specific task if it is completed.**

1. show notification everyday until specified date is arrived
2. Show notification every monday until specified date is arrived
3. Show notification monthly every specified day until specifed date is arrived

> **Problem:**

1. I do not know how to schedule repeat notification for given conditions
2. Is there any limit of notification per app? suppose I have 100 of task and each task may have any of the notification bounded with the uppar given conditions.

Please tell me what could be done? and how I can fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 3):

> show notification everyday until specified date is arrived

This is to display a message at a specific time every day

```
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 10
    dateComponents.minute = 30
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    if trigger.nextTriggerDate() >= your_specified_date {
        return
    }
```

> Is there any limit of notification per app? suppose I have 100 of task
>   and each task may have any of the notification bounded with the uppar
>   given conditions.

[Yes, there are limits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification). The system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest.

Comment: how it will get stop by it self?

Comment: if the date of the next notification is greater than or equal to the date when the notification should stop (`nextTriggerDate() >= your_specified_date`, the function will exit (return will be called) @A.s.ALI

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I think you did not understood the question. For example user has list of task, he set reminder (notification in our case) for his first task from the list. And for that task he sets the option to notify everyday ( as I mentioned above in question about the type of notification) 

And he sets end date as 4 years from today. so now this code does not seems to be working. Right? as user can close the app and never come back to app

Comment: I mean to say that if he sets stop date let suppose 2 days after today, and he does not come back to app, how it is going to stop by itself?

I think now I am clear??

Answer (score 2):

### Notification schedule for custom date with body

```
func schedulingNotificationForCustomDate(body: String, currentDate: Date) {
        // Configure User Notification Center
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = ""
        content.subtitle = ""
        content.body = body
        content.categoryIdentifier = "WeekDay notification"
        content.userInfo = ["NotificationID": "WeekDay notification", "repeat": true, "reschedule": false]
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "WeekDay notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

### Create date as per requirement

```
extension Date {
    static func createDate(weekday: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, year: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = hour
        components.minute = minute
        components.year = year
        components.month = calendar.component(.month, from: Date())
        components.day = calendar.component(.day, from: Date())
        components.weekday = weekday // sunday = 1 ... saturday = 7
        components.timeZone = .current
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
       }
    }
```

### Get the next date for scheduling repeat notification

```
extension Date {
    static func nextNthDateFromCurrentDate(FromDate: Date, numberOfDays: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: numberOfDays, to: FromDate)! // where numberOfDays is the number of days for the next date
    }
}
```

### For scheduling notification call

```
self.schedulingNotificationForCustomDate(body: body, currentDate: Date.nextNthDateFromCurrentDate(FromDate: Date.createDate(weekday: 2, hour: 11, minute: 00, year: year), numberOfDays: 14))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no end date specification on repeating local notifications, so unfortunately you will need to build something custom. However this is a limit of 64 notifications you may queue up according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification).

> An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the
>   system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically
>   rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and
>   discards the rest.

I would have an extension that can grab the dates between two dates like so:

```
extension Date {
    static func dates(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> [Date] {
        var dates: [Date] = []
        var date = fromDate

        while date <= toDate {
            dates.append(date)
            guard let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) else { break }
            date = newDate
        }
        return dates
    }
}
```

Then you can grab the dates that you need and iterate through each one to create a notification:

```
let threeDaysFromNowExample = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 3, to: Date())!
let dates = Date.dates(from: Date(), to: threeDaysFromNowExample)

for date in dates {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.alertBody = "Your alert here!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Did not test this code, but should get you started. You may need to massage the extension some to add the ability to grab only Mondays for example.

Comment: I thought this solution too, but to my bad luck I can not do it as we know that there is limit of 64 notifications. So do not you think that if my specified end date of notification is 2 years and user set reminder for the task fro every dat, so by using your code I will face problem of limit. And it is for just one task, user may have more tasks in list.

Comment: I guess you could build some sort of queue locally and check how many notifications you have already created, if it's lower than 64, create notifications until you have 64. Keep checking it everytime the user opens the app. The other solution would be to build out a backend and use push notifications.